# Todo application for Mac that imports Abstract Spoon's ToDoList files?

Tags: macos, mac, to-do

I'm currently switching from a Windows PC to MacBook Pro. I have extensive ToDo lists (for past and current projects) in [Abstract Spoon's ToDoList app](http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html).

Is there any similar Mac application that imports those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my best option is freemind. Not exactly a todo list, but Abstract Spoon's TodoList exports to Freemind format, which is available on the Mac.